# C++ Creating threads in loop and store them in vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops

I am working with threads for the first time in C++ and I would like to know what is wrong with my code.

I am working on Boruvka`s algorithm and I would like to make threads for finding the shortest Edge for component.

Here is my code:

```
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<Edge> minEdges;

    for (auto g: components) {
        Edge minEd;
        minEdges.push_back(minEd);
        threads.push_back(std::thread (findPath, g, std::ref(minEdges.back())));
    }
    for (auto &i : threads) {
        i.join();
    }
    for (Edge edge:minEdges) {
        if (!contains(mst, edge)) {
            addEdge(&mst, edge.n1, edge.n2, edge.weight);
        }
    }

void findPath(Graph &component, Edge &edge) 
//finds cheapest edge
```

For exlanation, I would like to give the component and a reference to an element in `minEdges` where will be stored the cheapest edge. Then I want to join all the threads and put all minimum edges to the mst.

This code gives me an error on line, where I`m pushing threads to the vector, but I could not find why. So can you please tell me?

Error message(i just deleted paths to the files):

```
  In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(Graph, std::reference_wrapper<Edge>))(Graph&, Edge&)>':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/thread:142:59:   
required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(Graph&, Edge&); _Args = {Graph&, std::reference_wrapper<Edge>}]'
 graph.cpp:232:82:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/functional:1505:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(Graph, std::reference_wrapper<Edge>))(Graph&, Edge&)>'
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/functional:1526:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(Graph, std::reference_wrapper<Edge>))(Graph&, Edge&)>'
     _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
     ^
                                                         ^
```

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: What happens when you use a std::ref on g as well?

Comment: Off topic: passing references to vector elements into a thread while pushing items into the vector runs a high risk of the references being rendered invalid by a resize before the threads get a chance to run.

Comment: Pass a lambda to the thread instead of using bind-style construction - that gives you more control over what happens and can result in better performance.

Comment: @Niall I've read that it should pass the reference, because thread is copying parameters. But removing it does not change anything at this point.

Comment: Reference to `g` is currently dangerous: `for (auto g: components)` If I'm not on crack, g is a temporary copy. Easily fixed, though `auto & g: components`

Comment: "I am working with threads" right there you've entered into a very unpleasant world of hurt and complexity. Unless you *really* have to use threads and *really* know what you are doing - don't!

Comment: also `std::ref(minEdges.back())` is dangerous - it may become invalid at the next iteration (while another thread is accessing it)

Comment: @RustyX - but does nothing to fix the data race..

Comment: You need to synchronize access to your shared state.

Comment: I wish that beginners would not use threads. They are hard enough (as in; very) to get right for experts.

Comment: @RustyX every thread should access its own element from `midEdges` at that point, so they will not modify same element, only same vector

Comment: @JesperJuhl I prefer not to use them, but I have to for passing my exam...

Comment: @TomášHodek - `push_back` can completely invalidate addresses of all already existing elements in a vector, by reallocating a bigger storage to accomodate the new element.

Comment: @RustyX you might be right, I didn't count with this. So I should just pass reference to the Edge and then just somehow get it from the thread?

Comment: Pro tip: `std::mutex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points...

1. Don't modify vectors which are already in use by other threads (adding to a vector can move other elements)
2. Iterate over references, not temporaries (`auto g`)
3. Prefer `emplace_back` whenever possible
4. Optionally try the lambda syntax
5. Use synchronization to be sure things happen in the order you think they would (not needed in your case - thread creation acts as a memory fence)

```
    std::vector<Edge> minEdges;
    for (auto &g: components) {
        minEdges.emplace_back();
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (size_t i=0; i<components.size(); ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back([&]{findPath(components[i], minEdges[i]);});
    }
    // rest of code...
```

Comment: You are missing the basic problem/point that when there are multiple threads in play, access to shared data structures *need to be* synchronized/serialized. No way around it - you have to use atomics or a lock if you update things in different threads - no amount of using references or emplace_back will save you. A data race is a data race.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - reading the same memory does not have to be synchronized if it is never modified. There is no data race here.

Comment: `minEdges` is modified in the main thread and accessed (read) in the other threads with no synchronization - there's a race there.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Pls refer C++11 standard section 30.3.1.2 thread constructors [thread.thread.constr] p5 : **the completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f**. Thread creation effectively acts as a memory fence.

Comment: but we don't know what happens in `findPath` post thread creation.

Comment: `findPath` acts on independent objects. Some people just can't admit they're wrong...

Comment: I can admit I'm wrong, I just need to be convinced first (don't be an ass about it - we're having a discusdion - I hope). And obviously you are right when independant objects are in play.