# Unable to create real multithreading in C++ (using for loop)

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop

I am new to C++ and I am trying to create multiple threads using for loop. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
class Threader{
   public:
        int foo(int z){
            std::cout << "Calling this function with value :" << z << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Threader *m;
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    std::thread t1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::thread t1(&Threader::foo, m, i);
        t1.join();

        }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output

[image]

As you can see the function I am calling is being invoked using Thread 5 times, but I have to do a `t1.join` inside the for loop. Without the `join` the for loop fails in the very first iteration. Like shown here [image]

But if I use the join(), then the threads are being created and executed sequentially cause join() waits for each thread completion. I could easily achieve Actual multithreading in Java by creating Threads in a loop using runnable methods.

How can I create 5 threads which would run absolutely parallel in C++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551371/creating-thread-inside-a-for-loop-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914279/c-creating-threads-in-loop-and-store-them-in-vector

Comment: Do not `join()` immediately. It will wait for thread finished.

Comment: You should save thread in a `vector` or somewhere. Please refer to the questions that Mat provided.

Comment: You need to maintain thread objects in a container. You are creating threads in for loop. As soon as next iteration starts, your previous thread object gets destroyed. This could be the probable cause for the exception.

Comment: The [thread destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) will call `terminate()` if it hasn't been `join`ed. So you have to store the thread objects outside the loop.

Comment: Also, you probably need a loop *inside* the thread, otherwise the first thread will likely complete while main() is creating the next one. So no multithreading anyway.